# It's a good idea to use error HTTP response codes different to 200 when an error occurs in server side?

Tags: ajax, api, rest, httpresponse

I understand that RESTful API must return HTTP codes according client request and server processing, but when we are processing an Ajax request with JSON response (form processing/validation, page status, etc...) it should return an specific HTTP error code or a 200 HTTP code with error message into JSON?

Some browsers have extensions that catch HTTP response code from header and some times overwrite server response with custom error pages (like worlderror.org). To avoid this, a 200 response always will as server sends.

It's a good method to response error codes from server when the client is a browser?

I know all ajax success and error methods to catch this errors from Javascript, but sometimes there are a man-in-the-middle that changes this response.

I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions about http responses, but all was focused to how to manage error responses and not if it's a good idea to use http codes when response can be altered.

Others like this [Is it considered good practice to return a code different than 200 from my controllers, in order to trigger an ajax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384063/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-return-a-code-different-than-200-from-my-contr) is not a explained response about a good practice.

RESTful API: client --> server --> client
Ajax Request: client --> browser --> server --> browser --> client

Finally, is this a good question to stackoverflow?